# Eclipse with Blackberry plugin hangs at "Analyzing source" when building the project

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I started blackberry project and selected build project, it went to 100% then stayed there with the message "Analyzing Sources".

I tried to compile several blackberry projects and got the same problem.

Re-installed eclipse and java jre and had no luck.

Environment:
I installed BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.5.2_indigo and BlackBerry Simulator_6.0.0.723_9700
OS: Windows 7 64
Jre 7 and 6 installed 32
Blackberry JRE 6

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try clicking the red stop button in the "Analyzing Sources" progress bar, sometimes, if you cancel hanged tasks in eclipse, it will continue

Comment: Tried that, it said "cancel requested" and the build stayed on. and I can't do any other action.

Comment: Restart, Reinstall, nothing has changed.